# How to set npm script to blank via the command line?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, npm-scripts

When I ran `npm set-script prepare ""` (using npm version 8.15.0 in a Windows command prompt), a warning was output:

`` npm WARN set-script set-script is deprecated, use `npm pkg set scripts.scriptname="cmd"` instead. ``

So I followed the above instruction with `npm pkg set scripts.prepare=""` and this time an error was output:

```
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm pkg set expects a key=value pair of args.
```

When I tried `npm pkg set scripts.prepare=" "` (note the space), this worked but it seems odd that a blank string isn't allowed. Is this a bug or a feature ...and is there another way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to remove the script you could use:

> npm pkg delete scripts.prepare

Comment: Yes - like that one - does seem cleaner to have nothing there. Maybe that was part of the reason for the deprecation.

Comment: RANT: They (npm) should give hint in error message, rather giving confusing error message. In my opinion they should not have such limitation, users should be free to  set empty value, not being forbidden to do so by tooling.